# Unreadable Categories in pdf export

Tags: php, mysql, highcharts

I get a proper highchart with all my elements and readable categories, see the picture

[image]

but if i want to export in PDF format i can't get readable categories at bottom of the file: see the picture:

[image]

here my code for the exporting module:

```
        xAxis: 
        {     
            categories: <?php echo json_encode($values); ?>
        },

    exporting: {
            enabled: true,
            type: 'image/jpeg',
            type: 'image/png',
            type: 'application/pdf',
            url: 'lib/hichart/exporting-server/php/index.php',
            filename: 'Graphique'   
        },
```

Anybody knows what i can change to get the categories readable?

THX in advance

Comment: Could you reproduce issue on jsFiddle?

Comment: It looks like problem with condifugation of your labels, do you use any CSS styles or useHTML option ? Could you reproduce this issue on the jsfiddle.net?

Comment: I see now that it works good with Chrome. It doesn't works only with IE6.
OK, i'll try it